# Add html support to PHP Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse

I downloaded eclipse for PHP and while code hinting works for most of PHP, their is none for just HTML. How can I fix that?

Comment: It looks like the WTP plugin should support the HTML content assist: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.sse.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Fcsrcedt004.html

Comment: Would you consider using the assembled package at http://www.phpeclipse.com/? That comes with all the HTML/CSS/JS syntax handling already baked in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eclipse for PHP is no longer supported ([clickity click](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/php_package.php)), so even if you find a way to do this it will not be supported anymore.

The Aptana plugin for Eclipse has great PHP and HTML assistance and I recommend it highly:
http://www.aptana.com/